# Why does my UITableViewFooter jump to the top?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = PromptInviteView.instantiateFromNib()
```

I've tried putting this in viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad.

Great, everything shows up and displays correctly.

However, if:

1. I push HOME and open 4-5 other apps, then return back to my app, the footer will "jump" to the top, covering the first row.
2. If I perform other actions inside the app (navigating back and forth), and then finally going back to his vc, then it will jump to the top also.

When I pull to refresh, all is good again. But if I don't do anything...the footer stays at the top (replacing the top row + is not clickable)

Does anyone know why this behavior is occurring, and how I can solve it?

**Update**: I realize that "drawRect" in my xib gets called when I open the app after 4-5 other apps.  And this is why the problem is happening.

In my drawRect code, I have this:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawRect(rect)
    inviteLabel.textColor = UIColor(hex: 0x404040)
    inviteLabel.text = STRINGS["PromptInviteLabelText"]
    inviteLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    inviteLabel.sizeToFit()



    inviteButton.setTitle(STRINGS["PromptInviteButtonText"], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    inviteButton.backgroundColor = FlatWatermelon()
    inviteButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    inviteButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(hex: 0xcccccc), forState: UIControlState.Selected)
    inviteButton.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
    inviteButton.clipsToBounds = true

    super.layoutSubviews() //this will allow the view's frame to be set.

    var padding = CGFloat(20.0)
    self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, CGRectGetMaxY(inviteButton.frame) + padding )


    var topBorder = UIView()
    topBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, 0.5)
    topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xededed)
    self.addSubview(topBorder)


    var bottomBorder = UIView()
    bottomBorder.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height, screenWidth, 0.5)
    bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: 0xededed)
    self.addSubview(bottomBorder)
}
```

How can I remove my code (especially the layoutSubview part) and put it somewhere else?

Is there another location where I should put the code? Is there a **didLayoutSubviews()** equivalent?

Comment: I would override layout sub views instead of draw rect. Literally you are configuring the sub views of `PromptInviteView`. You are not making any custom drawing.

Comment: @Desdenova - When I override it, how can I call super.layoutSubviews() ? I need to call it in order to set ```self.frame``` in the next line.  Is there a "didLayoutSubviews" equivalent?

Comment: You shouldn't be calling that manually in any case. Instead you need to use `setNeedsLayout` or `layoutIfNeeded`.

Comment: @Desdenova, could you show me an example of how you would do this? I tried replacing ```super.layoutSubviews()``` with your two suggestions (and both), and neither seemed to work.

Comment: Did you try `[self.tableView.tableFooterView setNeedsLayout]`? No idea how would you do that in swift though.